# Stop and restart command in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to Python and Spyder.
On the top right of the IPython console you find a red square button in order to stop the current command.
I had to do this several times. Afterwards, I wanted to restart (the adapted code), but nothing happens - no message, nothing.
After restarting, again nothing happened. I have no idea if the command was running or not - my guess is not because no output was produced. 
The only thing I could do was to close and restart Spyder.
Any suggestions how to stop and restart commands correctly?
How can I ensure that nothing is running in the background before restarting Spyder?

Comment: Is there a warning sign next to the red square? Use this, is will really kill the process.

Comment: no, there isn't anything like that

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Let me see if I understand you correctly: You run your code with `F5` after restarting your kernel and you got no output?

Comment: I run my code with F5 or F9 and after stopping it with the red button, I cannot rerun it. If I try to rerun it with F5 or F9 after stopping, nothing happens.

Comment: I am having this same issue. I do not want to restart the kernel, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: not really. The only solution is to close Spyder and to restart it again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but try this:

```
import sys
import os

def restart():
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

Then just add `restart()` at anytime in the script to restart it.